# How do I sort by distance from user, based on user's location?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 app in which users can search, sort, and filter to find parks and nature reserves. I'm using the Ransack gem.

I have calculated the distance of each park from the user based on the user's IP address using Javascript.

Now I want to add a link on the Parks Index page for users to sort by distance. (Currently I have sort by rating and sort by name.)

Not sure how to go about this... I suspect I'll have to store the distance in the database somehow (on the user table?), so I can apply a server-side sort. Is that the right approach?

How do I store the distance from user in an efficient way, when the distance is recalculated every time the user visits the site?

**app/javascript/controllers/geolocation_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';
import { getDistance, convertDistance } from 'geolib';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['park'];

  connect() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.setUserCoordinates(position.coords);
      this.setDistanceText();
    })
  }

  setUserCoordinates(coordinates) {
    this.element.dataset.latitude = coordinates.latitude;
    this.element.dataset.longitude = coordinates.longitude;
  }

  getUserCoordinates() {
    return {
      latitude: this.element.dataset.latitude,
      longitude: this.element.dataset.longitude,
    };
  }

  setDistanceText() {
    this.parkTargets.forEach((parkTarget) => {
      let distanceFrom = getDistance(
        this.getUserCoordinates(),
        { latitude: parkTarget.dataset.latitude,
          longitude: parkTarget.dataset.longitude },
      );

      parkTarget.querySelector('[data-distance-away]').innerHTML =
            `${Math.round(convertDistance(distanceFrom, 'km'))} kilometers away`;
    });
  }
}
```

**app/views/parks/_park_cards.erb**

```
<% @parks.order('average_rating DESC NULLS LAST').each do |park| %>
  <li
    style="list-style-type: none;"
    data-geolocation-target="park"
    data-latitude="<%= park.latitude %>"
    data-longitude="<%= park.longitude %>"
  >
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card border-0 px-2 mb-4">
        <% if park.default_image && park.default_image.content_type.in?(%w[image/gif image/jpeg image/png]) %>
          ...
        <% else %>
          ...
        <% end %>
        <div class="card-header border-0 bg-white mx-0 px-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <strong><%= link_to park.name, park, class: "text-body" %></strong>
          <div class="mx-0 px-0">
            <% if park.average_rating? %>
              <span>
                ...
              </span>
              <%= park.average_rating.round(2) %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div data-distance-away>
          </div>
          <div class="btn p-0 favorite-icon">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="btn p-0">
            ...
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/parks/index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Parks') %>
<div
  data-controller="geolocation"
  class="container-fluid"
  data-latitude=""
  data-longitude=""
>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <%- if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "New park", new_park_path %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-0 px-1 mb-5">
      <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <strong>
          <%= @parks.count %>
          <%= 'park'.pluralize(@parks.count) %>
        </strong>
        <span class="ms-4">
          <%= link_to "Clear all filters", parks_path, class: "btn link-dark" %>
        </span>
  </span>
      <span class="mb-5">
      </span>
      <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <%= sort_link(@q, :average_rating, "Sort by rating", default_order: :desc, class: "btn") %>
        <% if I18n.locale.to_s.include?('he') %>
          <%= sort_link(@q, :name_he, "Sort by name (Hebrew)", default_order: :asc, class: "btn") %>
        <% else %>
          <%= sort_link(@q, :name_en, "Sort by name", default_order: :asc, class: "btn") %>
        <% end %>
        <span class="d-flex justify-content-end ms-4">
          <%= render 'filters_button' %>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 mx-0 px-2">
    <%= render 'park_cards', parks: @parks %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 pagination">
    <%= will_paginate(@users) %>
  </div>


</div>

<%= render 'filters_modal' %>
```

**app/controllers/parks_controller.rb**

```
class ParksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_park, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :admin_user, only: %i[ new edit create update destroy ]

  # GET /parks or /parks.json
  def index
    @parks = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page:params[:page], :per_page => 48)
  end

  ...
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale
  before_action :set_search

  def set_search
    @q = Park.ransack(params[:q])
  end

  ...
```

Comment: You can use ruby gem to get the complete solution and this also provide sorting and many things: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: I actually have geocoder gem but I don't understand how it helps with the sorting issue. How do I apply a sort on data that's only calculated after getting the user's IP address? Am I missing something?

Comment: @nearby_parks = Park.near([user_latitiude, user_longitude], search_radius) use code like this and it will give near_by parks in sorted order

Comment: Thank you @LHH! Where do I include this code? In the parks controller? I'm not sure how it interacts with the Ransack `@q` variable in the sort link: 

      ```<%= sort_link(@q, :average_rating, "Sort by rating", default_order: :desc, class: "btn") %> ```